# Непонятный термин "Advertise-запрос" в контексте RestAPI. Что это?

Tags: c#, rest

В тестовом задании на разработку RestAPI-сервиса используется непонятный термин: `advertise-запрос`. Что это? Как с этим жить?

По условию задания, мы разрабатываем сервер статистики, а игровые сервера

> анонсируют себя advertise-запросами, затем присылают результаты
>   каждого завершенного матча.

```
PUT /servers/<endpoint>/info (advertise-запрос)

{
    "name": "] My P3rfect Server [",
    "gameModes": [ "DM", "TDM" ]
}
```

[Ссылка на задание](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wzNmTNJyHOrJxJOWLBPEN1HIxutrwQQROULwg9YdDL8/edit#).

Я не понимаю, что в данном контексте означает `advertise-запрос`.

Comment: может стоит спросить это у того, кто составлял задание?

Comment: вы уже задавали такой вопрос (со второй учётки :D ) и удалили... зачем вы это сделали? Неужели за все это время не было возможности спросить об этом того, кто дал задание?

Comment: Задавал вопрос прошлый не я.
Я решил задать его и оставить для потомков, т.к. это задание на стажировку, многим интересно будет.

Comment: А ответ на прошлый вопрос был получен тем человеком, а затем он удалил его.

Comment: И типа текст вы запомнили прошлого вопроса? ))) Собссн на него и тогда никто, кроме выдававшего задание не знал ответа и сейчас... Была только одна догадка что это есть такое... но догадка - не есть точное знание что это....так что это надо спросить именно "выдавателя задания"

Comment: Возможно Вы и правы, я просто загуглил и увидел какой-то клочёк ответа в гугле. Мне показалось, что ответ тому человеку дали, а далее он удалил вопрос. Вот и я решил спросить.

Comment: Спрошу у тех, кто дал задание.
Похоже, что никто кроме них и не знает что это такое.

Comment: Нужно больше контекста. Какая предметная область?

Comment: @Nofate Снизу человек дал ответ с примером кода из задания, которое дали мне.
Задание для стажёров по back-end'у, где требуется создать standalone-приложение, реализующее RESTful API.
Перечитав требования я понял, что по мнению людей, давших это задание - Advertise-запрос - это простой PUT запрос на URL, который выдаст ответ по данному запросу JSON'ом.
Но почему простой PUT запрос назвали Advertise я так и не понял.

Comment: @MaximShinkarev, я это понял. В том, API, которое вам задали реализовать, Advertise-запросом называется запрос, публикующий (рекламирующий) информацию о сервере в общем лобби, очевидно. Это не какой-то особый тип запроса в HTTP. Просто это часть того API. Наверняка там есть и удаляющий DELETE-запрос и много еще чего. Просто это не является общепринятым термином или чем-то таким.

Comment: Да, просто в компании придумали специфическое название для запроса.

Answer (score 2):

Advertise-запрос - это не часть RestAPI, а выдумка автора тестового задания или малораспространённый термин. Он обозначает RestAPI вызов, которым игровой сервер регистрирует себя в базе сервера статистики. Для этого используется приведенный запрос: `PUT /servers/<endpoint>/info`, именно этот анонсирующий запрос автор задания и назвал advertise-запросом.

В нотации RestAPI читается, как:

> Положить информацию о сервере `<endpoint>`

Запрос:

```
{
    "name": "] My P3rfect Server [",
    "gameModes": [ "DM", "TDM" ]
}
```

Comment: Сяпочки за правку серенькую :D

Comment: Почему мой ответ заминусовали, я ведь ответил правильно :с

Comment: Вероятно, потому что из ответа ничего не очевидно. Почему именно такой URI? Почему именно такая схема тела запроса? И что такое advertise-запрос?

Comment: Это было в задании, advertise запросом назван именно этот URI с таким запросом. Я и ответил. Нигде больше такого понятия нет.

Comment: Без дополнительной информации это просто PUT-запрос.

Comment: Так именно этот запрос и называется advertise  в данном случае ._.

Comment: Что за несправедливость :с

Comment: Нашел [исходный вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/623042). Похоже, это название конкретного API-вызова конкретного сервера в конкретной компании. Без этих подробностей ни вопрос ни ответ не несут никакой пользы.

Comment: Но ведь я же отвеетил :с

Comment: Я без уточнения узнал, где именно вопрос, дал в этой же области ответ, а меня минусуют. Что за люди :сссс

Comment: Вы понимаете, что без той части знаний, что осталась у вас в голове, даже сам вопрос бесполезен? Минуса, кстати, не ставил.

Comment: @ЗнающийЭльф: Берётесь реально помогать людям — помогайте лучше. Так, чтобы тот, кто пришёл сюда не зная ничего по теме, что-то интересное узнал. Без этого голый кусок кода никому не поможет. Думаю, за это и минусы.